# How to query for FiscalSettings.Name and have returned value be the year not the FiscalSettingsId

Tags: soql, custom-fiscal-year, fiscal-periods

My org has custom fiscal settings. I want to get back the start date, end date and year from the Period object.

Here is my query currently:

```
        List<Period> fiscalCalendar = [SELECT Type, StartDate, EndDate, 
                                       FiscalYearSettings.Name FROM Period WHERE Type = 'Year'];
```

The returned value is:

```
Period:{Type=Year, StartDate=2017-01-01 00:00:00, EndDate=2017-12-30 00:00:00, FiscalYearSettingsId=0220G000000TSaPQAW, Id=0260G000000WhU9QAK}, Period:{Type=Year, StartDate=2017-12-31 00:00:00, EndDate=2018-12-29 00:00:00, FiscalYearSettingsId=0220G000000TSajQAG, Id=0260G000000WhYgQAK}, ...)
```

I expected FiscalYearSettingsId to be FiscalYearSettingsName with an associated year such as '2010' or '2011'.

When I do the following query:

```
String fiscalYear = [SELECT FiscalYearSettings.Name FROM Period WHERE Type = 'Year' Limit 1].FiscalYearSettings.Name;
```

System.debug(fiscalYear);

The return value is something like '2010' or '2011' and this is what I expect.

My next thought is that the FiscalSettingsId in the first query needs to be used as a lookup to FiscalYearSettings sObject and then I can get the name property. For example:

```
FiscalSettingsId.FiscalYearSettings.Name
```

But this doesn't work.

If anyone can help me create one soql query to get the actual year along with the start and end date for a custom fiscal year, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The way to get to the field you want is `FiscalYearSettings.Name`

Comment: Op has used FiscalYearSettings.Name in the first query @ Sebastian

Comment: He has only shown that his debug statement doesn't display the field but the lack of error makes me think that's simply a strangeness in the debug.